Material-UI v5 and Next.js 14 integration not working with theming
I tried to follow https://v5.mui.com/material-ui/integrations/nextjs/ but I get an error crashing the whole application:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plain')
I am also using Typescript. My files look as follows:
my-project/app/theme.ts -> copied the source
'use client';
import { Roboto } from 'next/font/google';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const roboto = Roboto({
  weight: ['300', '400', '500', '700'],
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
});

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: roboto.style.fontFamily,
  },
});

export default theme;

my-project/app/layout.tsx
"use client"
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify"
import { cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider } from "aws-amplify/auth/cognito"
import { sessionStorage } from "aws-amplify/utils"
import { Suspense } from "react"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { store } from "@data/index"
import amplifyConfig from "@utils/amplifyConfig"
import RequireAuth from "@components/RequireAuth/RequireAuth"
import { AppRouterCacheProvider } from '@mui/material-nextjs/v13-appRouter';
import theme from "./theme"
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig)
cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.setKeyValueStorage(sessionStorage)

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>My shitty app</title>
            </head>
            <body style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0 }}>
                <AppRouterCacheProvider>
                    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                        <Provider store={store}>
                            <Suspense>
                                <RequireAuth>
                                    {children}
                                </RequireAuth>
                            </Suspense>
                        </Provider>
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </AppRouterCacheProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}

What am I doing wrong? Also I tried upgrading to MUI v6 and it wrecked my entire local dev environment to the point where yarn dev wouldn't start so I had to git clone again the whole thing... My immediate goal was just to style all the buttons to have border-radius: "20px"
[EDIT]: actually the errors come from @mui/joy which is also used in the project. I guess more work needs to be done to integrate theming with both MUI and Joy. Fair to say this caused me anything but Joy...

Fixed the issue by following these links:

https://mui.com/joy-ui/integrations/material-ui/
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/css-theme-variables/usage/

"use client"
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify"
import { cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider } from "aws-amplify/auth/cognito"
import { sessionStorage } from "aws-amplify/utils"
import { Suspense } from "react"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { store } from "@data/index"
import amplifyConfig from "@utils/amplifyConfig"
import RequireAuth from "@components/RequireAuth/RequireAuth"
import { AppRouterCacheProvider } from '@mui/material-nextjs/v15-appRouter';
import theme from "./theme"
import {
    extendTheme as materialExtendTheme,
    ThemeProvider as MaterialThemeProvider,
    THEME_ID as MATERIAL_THEME_ID,
} from '@mui/material/styles';
import { ThemeProvider as JoyThemeProvider } from '@mui/joy/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';

Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig)
cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.setKeyValueStorage(sessionStorage)

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>My Shitty App</title>
            </head>
            <body style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0 }}>
                <AppRouterCacheProvider>
                    <MaterialThemeProvider theme={{ [MATERIAL_THEME_ID]: theme }}>
                        <JoyThemeProvider>
                            <CssBaseline enableColorScheme />
                            <Provider store={store}>
                                <Suspense>
                                    <RequireAuth>
                                        {children}
                                    </RequireAuth>
                                </Suspense>
                            </Provider>
                        </JoyThemeProvider>
                    </MaterialThemeProvider>
                </AppRouterCacheProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}

